# Looping through each workbook in folder + pressing button VBA

Tags: excel, button, vba

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Optimize Macro Speed
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Press button in sheet 51
      wb.Worksheets("51").CommandButton1.Value = True

    'Save and Close Workbook
      'wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have a folder with 50 workbooks with the same worksheets in each workbook. I have 2 buttons in each of the worksheets in the workbook that allows me to download/upload to db. I need to loop through each workbook and have it press the upload button in sheet51.

wb.Worksheets("51").CommandButton1.Value = True

Can anyone look through what I'm doing wrong? I'm getting this message -- Run-time error: '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Just make the CommandButton1_Click code public and call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommandButtons don't have a `Value` property, so I think you want to invoke the button's `Click` event, i.e.:

```
wb.Worksheets("51").CommandButton1_Click
```

The `CommandButton1_Click` event will first need to be declared `Public`, rather than `Private`, i.e.:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
```

While it is declared Private, it can only be accessed by code within the worksheet itself.

---

*The following edit, for which I am very grateful, was made by Comintern:*

NOTE: If you don't want to manually change all of the event handler routines, you can simply change them from Private to Public by using VBA Extensibility:

```
'Requires a reference to Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility
'Also requires "Trust access to the VBA project object model" to be checked.
'in Macro Security.

Dim targetLine As Long

'The "51" in VBComponents("51") is the name of the code module which is usually, but
'not always, the same as the sheet name
With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("51").CodeModule
    targetLine = .ProcStartLine("CommandButton1_Click", vbext_pk_Proc)
    .ReplaceLine targetLine, "Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
End With

wb.Sheets("51").CommandButton1_Click
```

Comment: This makes me wonder if you can use VBA Extensibility to change the event handler to `Public` and ***then*** call it...

Comment: @Comintern - I've never even tried using the VBA Extensibility functions, so I will leave it to you to experiment with that if you want to.  (Post an answer if you succeed, and I will delete mine - an answer which gets around the `Private` issue will be of much more use to other people.)

Comment: The answer is yes, yes you can. *Recommending* it is a different story though - I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader unless you're curious.  If so, I can edit it into your answer (it really isn't horribly germane to the question).

Comment: @Comintern - I'm happy for you to edit my answer if you like, or not edit it if you think the method should only be attempted by people with enough knowledge that they wouldn't be looking at this question for an answer anyway, or possibly even put up your own question and self-answer for the more advanced users who might be interested.  (As for my curiosity, I might go investigate it now that you tell me it actually is feasible.)

Comment: @Comintern - Thanks - I edited your edit to (a) acknowledge your contribution, and (b) (most importantly) fix up the code indentation (very sloppy on your part ;-) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124489/discussion-between-comintern-and-yowe3k).

Comment: @Comintern - I inserted the code for VBA Extensibility in place of "wb.Worksheets("51").CommandButton1.Value = True" and now I'm getting a run-time error '9': Subscript out of range for the line "With wb.VBProject.VBComponents("6").CodeModule".

Comment: @wowmoo - You need to use the code module's name, not the sheet name. For example, if you have a sheet named "foo" and see `Sheet1 (foo)` in the project explorer window, you would need to use `VBComponents("Sheet1")`, not the worksheet name.

Comment: @Comintern - Okay got it. Now I'm getting a run-time error '35': "sub or function not defined" for targetLine = .ProcStartLine("CommandButton1_Click", vbext_pk_Proc) ...

Comment: @wowmoo - Is your click handler named `CommandButton1_Click`?

Comment: @Comintern got it to work. the vba extensibility was key. thank you!!